# Is this a valid way of ensuring uniqueness in Rails without a Unique Index?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, transactions

Is this a valid way of ensuring uniqueness in Rails without a Unique Index?

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.create params
    User.transaction do
      return false if find_by(email: params[:email])

      super
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: From what I know so far NO, Rails uniqueness validation cannot guarantee 100% because of race condition. I think better solution is to use that unique index on db and have proper handling on Rails application.

Comment: You have to use a unique index https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#uniqueness

Answer (score 0):

You can use ActiveRecord Uniqueness validation.
Validations are used to ensure that only valid data is saved into your database.
Model-level validations are the best way to ensure that only valid data is saved into your database. They are database agnostic, cannot be bypassed by end users, and are convenient to test and maintain. Rails makes them easy to use, provides built-in helpers for common needs, and allows you to create your own validation methods as well.

**Uniqueness**

```
class Account < ApplicationRecord
 validates :email, uniqueness: true
end
```

It does not create a uniqueness constraint in the database, so it may happen that two different database connections create two records with the same value for a column that you intend to be unique. To avoid that, you must create a unique index on that column in your database.

**When to use Database constraints?**
Database constraints and/or stored procedures make the validation mechanisms database-dependent and can make testing and maintenance more difficult. However, if your database is used by other applications, it may be a good idea to use some constraints at the database level. Additionally, database-level validations can safely handle some things (such as uniqueness in heavily-used tables) that can be difficult to implement otherwise.

[More on ActiveRecord validations](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html)